# Is this mac book pro recoverable?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, catalina

While scanning my HDD usng First Aid, I got this error:

```
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh SSD - Data was formatted by hfs_convert (1412.141.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.141.3.7.2).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
error: directory valence check: directory (oid 0x13): nchildren (1) does not match drec count (0) 
Verifying allocated space.
Performing deferred repairs.
error: Unable to perform deferred repairs without full space verification
error: Try running fsck against the entire APFS container instead of a volume
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.
```

Do you recommend getting new hard disk or is it not recoverable?

Comment: What model of MBP is this (year, model)? You can't replace the SSD on a Mac since 2017. Ideally, I'd take this to an Apple Store for assessment. How full is the disk? Have you tried running Disk Utility from Recovery?

Comment: Did you try running First Aid on the APFS container as suggested in error message?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention , its 2013 model. @benwiggy

Comment: Have you replaced the original hard drive with an SSD at some point? (The name "Macintosh SSD" suggests that you have.)

Answer (score 2):

You almost never have to replace a drive for this sort of error.

- Do you have a backup? Make that immediately if it’s not up to date. Get professional help if you would pay money to preserve anything. Don’t assume repair won’t erase everything, it’s not designed to, but any change can be the last one a drive makes, and failure often has no warning (or this is your warning - errors).

Consult the guide: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102611

- Choose show all devices in disk utility (see link above) and then try to repair each item that contains the one with an error. Repeat until the whole disk says it can’t be fixed.
- Repeat the step above booted from another OS. Recovery, external or internet recovery are all fine options and equivalent in function.
- Erase the drive (or seek professional data recovery service)
- Install updated OS after erasing the restore from backup.

Only if everything else fails, would hardware repair be needed. Hopefully it’s fixed on the first two steps. Feel free to edit in my answer if you solve it faster than the worst case.

Comment: okay, I can make a backup, however I want to let you know its an old macbook pro from 2013, and I am assuming switching to ssd would make it faster.

Comment: You will be delighted with SSD and based on which you choose it may stay fast for the entire life of that Mac and still be usable after the Mac stops working. Get the SSD and test it with external enclosure - make sure OS runs and then put it inside the Mac is my advice there @Ciastopiekarz